# Error al intentar envíar un email - android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException

Tags: java, android, android-studio

en mi aplicación necesito poder enviar un email. El usuario escribe su nombre, correo electrónico y una descripción en una serie de `editText` y mediante un `Button` quiero que se envíen esos datos a mi correo electrónico. He estado mirando la librería de JavaMail y probablemente mi problema sea una mala utilización de la misma.

Aquí está el `setOnClickListener` del `Button`, en el cual he escrito el código para enviar el email. El error me lo da en la línea `javax.mail.Transport.send(msg);`

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Properties props = new Properties();

            props.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
            props.setProperty("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
            props.put("mail.transport.protocol","smtp");
            props.put("mail.smtp.port",25);
            props.setProperty("mail.smtp.user", "ejemplo@gmail.com");
            props.setProperty("mail.smtp.auth", "true");

            Session mailSession = Session.getInstance(props,null);

            Message msg = new MimeMessage(mailSession);

            //Establecemos el asunto, el remitente y el destinatario
            try{
                msg.setSubject(etNombre.getText().toString());
                msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(etEmail.getText().toString(),etNombre.getText().toString()));
                msg.addRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress[] { new InternetAddress("ejemplo@gmail.com") });
            }catch (javax.mail.MessagingException ex){
                ex.getMessage();
            }
            catch (java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException e){
                e.getMessage();
            }

            //Mensaje que se quiere enviar (cuerpo del mensaje)
            DataHandler dh = new DataHandler(etMensaje.getText().toString(),"text/plain");
            try {
                msg.setDataHandler(dh);
            } catch (MessagingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            //Línea para envíar el mensaje
            try {
                javax.mail.Transport.send(msg);
            } catch (MessagingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    });
```

El error que me da es el siguiente:

```
08-24 18:42:42.037 23504-23504/es.uclm.mylittlepets E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                  Process: es.uclm.mylittlepets, PID: 23504
                                                                  android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
                                                                      at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1273)
                                                                      at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:431)
                                                                      at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:409)
                                                                      at javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress.getLocalAddress(InternetAddress.java:517)
                                                                      at javax.mail.internet.UniqueValue.getUniqueMessageIDValue(UniqueValue.java:99)
                                                                      at javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.updateMessageID(MimeMessage.java:2054)
                                                                      at javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.updateHeaders(MimeMessage.java:2076)
                                                                      at javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.saveChanges(MimeMessage.java:2042)
                                                                      at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:117)
                                                                      at es.uclm.mylittlepets.Layout.Contacto$1.onClick(Contacto.java:78)
                                                                      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
                                                                      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
                                                                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

SEGUNDO ERROR.
Haciendo lo que dice el usuario/a Elenasys, el error que da es: `08-25 08:53:33.061 7556-7556/es.uclm.mylittlepets E/Error: Exception: null`. En el `try-catch`está tomando el catch y printeando el error.

Mi código es este:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try{
                        procesoEnviarMail();
                    }catch (Exception ex){
                        Log.e("Error", "Exception: " + ex.getMessage());                        }
                }
            });

        }
    });
```

El método `procesoEnviarMail()` simplemente tiene todo el código escrito anteriormente en el lugar en el que ahora se encuentra este `try-catch`.

Nuevo error en: `javax.mail.Transport.send(msg);`

```
08-25 11:58:13.676 7782-7782/es.uclm.mylittlepets E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                Process: es.uclm.mylittlepets, PID: 7782
                                                                android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
                                                                    at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1273)
                                                                    at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:431)
                                                                    at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:409)
                                                                    at javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress.getLocalHostName(InternetAddress.java:568)
                                                                    at javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress._getLocalAddress(InternetAddress.java:547)
                                                                    at javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress.getLocalAddress(InternetAddress.java:518)
                                                                    at javax.mail.internet.UniqueValue.getUniqueMessageIDValue(UniqueValue.java:100)
                                                                    at javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.updateMessageID(MimeMessage.java:2172)
                                                                    at javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.updateHeaders(MimeMessage.java:2200)
                                                                    at javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.saveChanges(MimeMessage.java:2159)
                                                                    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:123)
                                                                    at es.uclm.mylittlepets.Layout.Contacto.procesoEnviarMail(Contacto.java:110)
                                                                    at es.uclm.mylittlepets.Layout.Contacto$1$1.run(Contacto.java:49)
                                                                    at android.app.Activity.runOnUiThread(Activity.java:5511)
                                                                    at es.uclm.mylittlepets.Layout.Contacto$1.onClick(Contacto.java:42)
                                                                    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
                                                                    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
                                                                    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Answer (score 2):

El problema es que estas realizando esta tarea en el hilo principal, puedes usar runOnUIThread para ejecutar tu método.

> **NetworkOnMainThreadException**: se provoca cuando tratas de realizar
>   operaciones en el hilo principal (Main thread), lo cual es incorrecto.

Usa [**runOnUiThread()**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread(java.lang.Runnable))

```
 @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {  
                   procesoEnviaEmail(); //Realizar aquí tu proceso!                    

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("Error", "Exception: " + e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        });
}
```

Otras opciones seria usar [**Asyncask**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) o [**Handler.post()**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#post(java.lang.Runnable))

Comment: He actualizado información con un nuevo error que me salta al implementar ese código

Comment: Ok Ivan,  es otro error, quita el try - catch y dime que error obtienes?

Comment: Ya está actualizado con el error, es el mismo de antes.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacer lo siguiente, usando un Intent, y seteas los valores que quieras que tenga el email ( los obtenes de los edittext)
>

> ```
> String recepientEmail = "etEmail.getText().toString()"; // aca va donde quieres enviar el email  
> Intent intentt = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO); // esto lo dejas como esta
> intentt.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:" + recepientEmail)); // aca seteas a que direccion va el email con la variable recipientEmail)
> intentt.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Sugerencia");// este es el asunto de email
> intentt.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Escribe tu sugerencia aqui"); // este es el contenido del email
> startActivity(intentt);
> ```

Lo unico que tienes que hacer es obtener el texto de cada edittext y setearlos en el codigo. El intent lo pones dentro de la accion Onclick de tu boton enviar.

Entonces deberias cambiar donde dice "Sugerencia" y "Escribe tu email aqui" por el texto de tus edittext. Por ejemplo:

> ```
> intentt.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "TU_EDITTEXT.gettext().toString()"); // asunto del email
>
> intentt.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "TU_EDITTEXT.gettext().toString()"); // cuerpo del email
> ```

Espero que te sirva. Saludos!